# Connecting the Foreign key from the table which is present in the same DB using 2 Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices

I want to create a Foreign key as a reference from the user table to easily store and retrieve the messages , the problem is for the spring boot microservices I want to run 2 Spring boot App , one is for user authentication and another one for storing messages . So how to connect the foreign key as a ref of the user table from 2 diff spring boot Applications ?

**Tables in the DB :**

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_spamspring |
+----------------------+
| _user                |
| message              |
+----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Table user :**
mysql> desc _user;

```
+----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type                     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid      | bigint                   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(50)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(50)              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password | varchar(255)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| role     | enum('ADMIN','CUSTOMER') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Table messages :**

```
mysql> desc message;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | bigint       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| content   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timestamp | datetime(6)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id   | bigint       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Message Entity :**

```
package com.message.userMessage.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import lombok.Data;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
@Data
@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long userId; // Foreign key to the User table
    private String content;
    private LocalDateTime timestamp;
}
```

**User Entity :**

```
package com.spam.shield.model;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
// All imports

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long uid;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String email;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your constraints but it seems that you should have two separate databases.

If you want to keep a single database:

- Create a user entity with just an ID and map it to message
- Do it directly in the database

Otherwise, once separated, you have 2 options:

- Do not do it. Do a possible check before inserting it into the database. But that's all.
- Share the same database (strongly not recommended)
- Duplicate your data in your second service (strongly discouraged)

The last two "false" solutions break the principle of independence between micro services.

That being said, you can simply store the auth id in the JWT.
Once the signature is verified, you can trust it and therefore reuse this ID as a safe value.